# Variable "name" does not exist

Tags: php, doctrine, twig, symfony-3.2

This is my **DefaultController.php** file i want to fetch data of firstname on my dashboard while login to dashboard page. but i am getting 'Variable "name" does not exist.' error,  i am new in symfony i know that code is very complicated, can anyone help me i stuck this task last two days.

**DefaultController.php**

```
<?php
namespace AppBundle\Controller;
use AppBundle\Entity\users;
use AppBundle\Entity\Login;
use Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\Configuration\Route;
use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\RedirectResponse;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Session\Session;




class DefaultController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * @Route("/", name="homepage")
     */
    public function indexAction(Request $request)
    {
        $session = $request->getSession();
        $user_id = $session->get('user_id');
        if(isset($user_id) && $user_id != ''){
            return $this->render('default/index.html.twig');
        }else{
            return $this->redirectToRoute('login');
        }   
    }



    /**
     * @Route("/blog", name="blog")
     */
    public function blogAction(Request $request)
    {

        return $this->render('default/blog.html.twig');

    }

    /**
     * @Route("/signup", name="signup")
     */


    public function signupAction(Request $request)
    {

        return $this->render('default/signup.html.twig');

    }



    /**
     * @Route("/bootstrap_elements", name="bootstrap_elements")
     */

    public function bootstrap_elementsAction(Request $request)
    {

        return $this->render('default/bootstrap_elements.html.twig');

    }

    /**
     * @Route("/bootstrap_grid", name="bootstrap_grid")
     */
    public function bootstrap_gridAction(Request $request)
    {

        return $this->render('default/bootstrap_grid.html.twig');

    }

    /**
     * @Route("/forms", name="forms")
     */
    public function formsAction(Request $request)
    {

        return $this->render('default/forms.html.twig');

    }

    /**
     * @Route("/portfolio", name="portfolio")
     */
    public function portfolioAction(Request $request)
    {

        return $this->render('default/portfolio.html.twig');

    }

    /**
     * @Route("/register", name="register")
     */

    public function registerAction(Request $request)
    {


            if($request->getMethod()=='POST'){

                $username=$request->get('username');
                $firstname=$request->get('firstname');
                $password=$request->get('password');

                $user = new Users();
                $user->setUserName($username);
                $user->setFirstName($firstname);
                $user->setPassword($password);
                $em=$this->getDoctrine()->getEntityManager();
            $em->persist($user);
            $em->flush();



    }   

    return $this->render('default/register.html.twig');

    }




    /**
     * @Route("/timeline", name="timeline")
     */
    public function timelineAction(Request $request)
    {

        return $this->render('default/timeline.html.twig');

    }

    /**
     * @Route("/typography", name="typography")
     */
    public function typographyAction(Request $request)
    {

        return $this->render('default/typography.html.twig');

    }





    /**
     * @Route("/login", name="login")
     */

    public function loginAction(Request $request)
    {
        $session = $request->getSession();
        $user_id = $session->get('user_id');

        if(isset($user_id) && $user_id != ''){
            return $this->redirectToRoute('homepage');
        }else{
            $em=$this->getDoctrine()->getEntityManager();
            $repository=$em->getRepository('AppBundle:users');


            if($request->getMethod()=='POST')
            {

            $this->get('session')->clear();
            $username=$request->get('username');
            $password=$request->get('password');
            $remember=$request->get('remember');

            $user=$repository->findOneBy(array('userName'=>$username, 'password'=>$password)); 

            if($user)
            {
    /*          echo "<pre>";
                print_r($user);
                exit; */

                $session->set('user_id', $user->getId());
                $session->set('name', $user->getFirstName());


                /* if($remember=='remember-me')
                {
                    $login=new Login();
                    $login->setUserName($username);
                    $login->setPassword($password);
                    $session->set('login', $login);
                } */
              //  return $this->render('default/index.html.twig');

                return $this->render('default/index.html.twig', array('name' => $user->getFirstName()  ));


            }
            else
                {
                return $this->render('default/login.html.twig', array('name' => 'Login Error'));
            }
            }
            else{

                if ($session->has('login'))
                {
                    $login=$session->get('login');
                    $username=$login->getUserName();
                    $password=$login->getPassword();
                    $user=$repository->findOneBy(array('userName'=>$username, 'password'=>$password));

                    if($user)
                        {   
                            return $this->render('default/index.html.twig');
                        }       

                }

                return $this->render('default/login.html.twig');

            } 
        }   
    }





    /**
     * @Route("/logout", name="logout")
     */

    public function logoutAction(Request $request)
    {
    $session = $request->getSession();
    $this->get('session')->clear();
    return $this->redirectToRoute('login');
    }

}
```

This is my **base.html.twig** in this file i have included my header and sidebar which i have used in my all files.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Dashboard - Deep Blue Admin</title>

    {% block stylesheets %}

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ asset('templates/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css') }}" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ asset('templates/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css') }}" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ asset('templates/css/local.css') }}" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{{ asset('http://www.shieldui.com/shared/components/latest/css/light-bootstrap/all.min.css') }}" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ asset('templates/css/2.css') }}">

    {% endblock %}

    {% block javascripts %}
    <script src="{{asset('templates/js/jquery-1.10.2.min.js') }}"></script>
    <script src="{{ asset('templates/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js') }}"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="{{ asset('http://www.shieldui.com/shared/components/latest/js/shieldui-all.min.js') }}"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="{{ asset('http://www.prepbootstrap.com/Content/js/gridData.js') }}"></script>




    <!-- you need to include the shieldui css and js assets in order for the charts to work -->


</head>

<body>
    <div id="wrapper">
        <nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top" role="navigation">
            <div class="navbar-header">
                <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-ex1-collapse">
                    <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                </button>
                <a class="navbar-brand" href="">Admin Panel</a>
            </div>
            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse navbar-ex1-collapse">
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav side-nav">
                    <li class="active"><a href=""><i class="fa fa-bullseye"></i> Dashboard</a></li>
                    <li><a href="{{ ('portfolio') }}"><i class="fa fa-tasks"></i> Portfolio</a></li>
                    <li><a href="{{ ('blog') }}"><i class="fa fa-globe"></i> Blog</a></li>
                    <li><a href="{{ ('signup') }}"><i class="fa fa-list-ol"></i> SignUp</a></li>
                    <li><a href="{{ ('register') }}"><i class="fa fa-font"></i> Register</a></li>
                    <li><a href="{{ ('timeline') }}"><i class="fa fa-font"></i> Timeline</a></li>
                    <li><a href="{{ ('forms') }}"><i class="fa fa-list-ol"></i> Add Product</a></li>
                    <li><a href="{{ ('typography') }}"><i class="fa fa-font"></i> Typography</a></li>
                    <li><a href="{{ ('bootstrap_elements') }}"><i class="fa fa-list-ul"></i> Bootstrap Elements</a></li>
                    <li><a href="{{ ('bootstrap_grid') }}"><i class="fa fa-table"></i > Bootstrap Grid</a></li>    
                </ul>
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right navbar-user">
                    <li class="dropdown messages-dropdown">
                        <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown"><i class="fa fa-envelope"></i> Messages <span class="badge">2</span> <b class="caret"></b></a>
                        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                            <li class="dropdown-header">2 New Messages</li>
                            <li class="message-preview">
                                <a href="#">
                                    <span class="avatar"><i class="fa fa-bell"></i></span>
                                    <span class="message">Security alert</span>
                                </a>
                            </li>
                            <li class="divider"></li>
                            <li class="message-preview">
                                <a href="#">
                                    <span class="avatar"><i class="fa fa-bell"></i></span>
                                    <span class="message">Security alert</span>
                                </a>
                            </li>
                            <li class="divider"></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Go to Inbox <span class="badge">2</span></a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>


                     <li class="dropdown user-dropdown">



                      <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown"><i class="fa fa-user"></i> {{name}}<b class="caret"></b></a>




                        <ul class="dropdown-menu">


                            <li><a href="{{path('logout')}}"><i class="fa fa-power-off"></i> Log Out</a></li>

                        </ul>
                    </li>
            </div>
        </nav>


        {% block body %}{% endblock %}
    <!-- /#wrapper -->



    <script type="text/javascript">
        jQuery(function ($) {
            var performance = [12, 43, 34, 22, 12, 33, 4, 17, 22, 34, 54, 67],
                visits = [123, 323, 143, 132, 274, 223, 143, 156, 223, 223],
                budget = [23, 19, 11, 34, 42, 52, 35, 22, 37, 45, 55, 57],
                sales = [11, 9, 31, 34, 42, 52, 35, 22, 37, 45, 55, 57],
                targets = [17, 19, 5, 4, 62, 62, 75, 12, 47, 55, 65, 67],
                avrg = [117, 119, 95, 114, 162, 162, 175, 112, 147, 155, 265, 167];

            $("#shieldui-chart1").shieldChart({
                primaryHeader: {
                    text: "Visitors"
                },
                exportOptions: {
                    image: false,
                    print: false
                },
                dataSeries: [{
                    seriesType: "area",
                    collectionAlias: "Q Data",
                    data: performance
                }]
            });

            $("#shieldui-chart2").shieldChart({
                primaryHeader: {
                    text: "Login Data"
                },
                exportOptions: {
                    image: false,
                    print: false
                },
                dataSeries: [
                    {
                        seriesType: "polarbar",
                        collectionAlias: "Logins",
                        data: visits
                    },
                    {
                        seriesType: "polarbar",
                        collectionAlias: "Avg Visit Duration",
                        data: avrg
                    }
                ]
            });

            $("#shieldui-chart3").shieldChart({
                primaryHeader: {
                    text: "Sales Data"
                },
                dataSeries: [
                    {
                        seriesType: "bar",
                        collectionAlias: "Budget",
                        data: budget
                    },
                    {
                        seriesType: "bar",
                        collectionAlias: "Sales",
                        data: sales
                    },
                    {
                        seriesType: "spline",
                        collectionAlias: "Targets",
                        data: targets
                    }
                ]
            });

            $("#shieldui-grid1").shieldGrid({
                dataSource: {
                    data: gridData
                },
                sorting: {
                    multiple: true
                },
                paging: {
                    pageSize: 7,
                    pageLinksCount: 4
                },
                selection: {
                    type: "row",
                    multiple: true,
                    toggle: false
                },
                columns: [
                    { field: "id", width: "70px", title: "ID" },
                    { field: "name", title: "Person Name" },
                    { field: "company", title: "Company Name" },
                    { field: "email", title: "Email Address", width: "270px" }
                ]
            });
        });
    </script>
{% endblock %}

</body>

</html>


**index.html.twig**

This is my **index.html.twig**  in this file i have included my 'base.html.twig' in this file.


{% extends "::base.html.twig" %}



{% block body %}

<div id="page-wrapper">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-lg-12">
                    <h1>Dashboard <small>Dashboard Home</small></h1>
                    <div class="alert alert-success alert-dismissable">
                        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
                        Welcome to the admin dashboard!
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-lg-3">
                    <div class="panel panel-default ">
                        <div class="panel-body alert-info">
                            <div class="col-xs-5">
                                <i class="fa fa-truck fa-5x"></i>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-xs-5 text-right">
                                <p class="alerts-heading">0</p>
                                <p class="alerts-text">New Orders</p>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-lg-3">
                    <div class="panel panel-default ">
                        <div class="panel-body alert-info">
                            <div class="col-xs-5">
                                <i class="fa fa-money fa-5x"></i>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-xs-5 text-right">
                                <p class="alerts-heading">0</p>
                                <p class="alerts-text">Income</p>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-lg-3">
                    <div class="panel panel-default ">
                        <div class="panel-body alert-info">
                            <div class="col-xs-5">
                                <i class="fa fa-twitter fa-5x"></i>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-xs-5 text-right">
                                <p class="alerts-heading">0</p>
                                <p class="alerts-text">Mentions</p>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-lg-3">
                    <div class="panel panel-default ">
                        <div class="panel-body alert-info">
                            <div class="col-xs-5">
                                <i class="fa fa-download fa-5x"></i>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-xs-5 text-right">
                                <p class="alerts-heading">0</p>
                                <p class="alerts-text">Downloads</p>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-lg-8">
                    <div class="panel panel-primary">
                        <div class="panel-heading">
                            <h3 class="panel-title"><i class="fa fa-bar-chart-o"></i> Sales personnel Data</h3>
                        </div>
                        <div class="panel-body">
                            <div id="shieldui-grid1"></div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-lg-4">
                    <div class="panel panel-primary">
                        <div class="panel-heading">
                            <h3 class="panel-title"><i class="fa fa-bar-chart-o"></i> Logins per week</h3>
                        </div>
                        <div class="panel-body">
                            <div id="shieldui-chart2"></div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-lg-12">
                    <div class="panel panel-primary">
                        <div class="panel-heading">
                            <h3 class="panel-title"><i class="fa fa-bar-chart-o"></i> Sales Data</h3>
                        </div>
                        <div class="panel-body">
                            <div id="shieldui-chart3"></div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    {% endblock %}


**users.php**

This is my **users.php** file i have used this file as a database.

<?php

namespace AppBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * users
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="users")
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="AppBundle\Repository\usersRepository")
 */
class users
{
    /**
     * @var int
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="user_name", type="string", length=255)
     */
    private $userName;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="first_name", type="string", length=255)
     */
    private $firstName;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="password", type="string", length=255)
     */
    private $password;


    /**
     * Get id
     *
     * @return int
     */
    public function getId()
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    /**
     * Set userName
     *
     * @param string $userName
     *
     * @return users
     */
    public function setUserName($userName)
    {
        $this->userName = $userName;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get userName
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getUserName()
    {
        return $this->userName;
    }

    /**
     * Set firstName
     *
     * @param string $firstName
     *
     * @return users
     */
    public function setFirstName($firstName)
    {
        $this->firstName = $firstName;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get firstName
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getFirstName()
    {
        return $this->firstName;
    }

    /**
     * Set password
     *
     * @param string $password
     *
     * @return users
     */
    public function setPassword($password)
    {
        $this->password = $password;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get password
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getPassword()
    {
        return $this->password;
    }
}
```

Comment: You have to define this {{name}} name variable in your controller parameter before use.

Comment: Sir where i can define {{name}} because i am new in symfony

Comment: I think you should read this https://symfony.com/doc/current/templating/embedding_controllers.html

Answer (score 0):

```
// src/AppBundle/Controller/DefaultController.php
class DefaultController extends Controller
{
    public function yourAction()
    {
        $name = 'somethinghere';

        return $this->render('yourtwigfile.html.twig', array(
            'name' => $name,
        ));
    }

    // ...
}
```

and in your twig file your twig filename.html.twig...

```
Your name here {{ name }}
```